# CodeIgniter 2.1, PHP - find a day in array, take that day plus six more and remove the rest from the array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array which represent all month. How can I find today's day in the array, take that day, plus next six days (not necessary six days) and remove rest from the array?

For example:

```
$days = array('1', '2', '3', ... '28', '29', '30');
```

I need 3-9. How can I do this?

Comment: And when you have the 30th and add 6 days what happens? Use PHP's date libraries. Take some time to learn them, they will be more useful to you than manually adding numbers together to build dates. http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: I think I had write the question a little unclear. I have one month from today, including days for the following month. And I use this array on several places - but on one place I need to show this day and next seven days. So, for the moment I think that the best way to do this is to find today in the array, take next six days and cut off the rest of them. Maybe my logic is bad at the moment, but I can not think of something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look at another way of doing whatever it is you want to do. But here is a solution for what you asked:

```
$days = range(1, date('t'));
$days_forward = 6;


$key = array_search(date('j'), $days);
if($key === FALSE)
  die('Date not found in array');

$days = array_slice($days, $key, $days_forward + 1);

print_r($days);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 19
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 21
    [3] => 22
    [4] => 23
    [5] => 24
    [6] => 25
)
```

Comment: I was in bit of a rush, and had not time to give you feedback. This is what I needed. Thank you for your help :)